# jwysiwyg insert text at cursor using custom control

Tags: javascript, jquery, jwysiwyg

How would I do this? Here is the custom control we have:

```
customcontrol:{   
  groupIndex: 6,
  visible: true,
  icon: 'includes/images/controlimage.png',
  custom:true,
  exec: function (){
    $('#editor').wysiwyg('setContent',   $('#editor').val() + 'texttoinsert');
  },
  tooltip:"Insert text at cursor"
}
```

I've tried other solutions to insert text in a text area, but none of them work (nothing happens at all, no errors) or they were not designed to work with the custom controls.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem and the solution was quite simple:

```
my_button: { 
    visible: true,
    groupIndex: 100,
    tooltip: "button",
    exec: function()
    {
        $("selector").wysiwyg('insertHtml', 'some text');
    }
}
```